# calculate Row Wise Sum - Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

This is My table :

```
ID              Q1         Q2           Q3            Q4
----------------------------------------------------------------
20130712        NULL       728.63       NULL            NULL
20130712        8881.55    9673.68      2629.566        6251.984
20130713        1813       1813         84.49           1728.51
20130714        3632.65    3632.65      1209.412        2423.238
20130714        70.758     2637.43      70.758          0
20130714        1601.578   3569.73      204.745         1396.833
20130714        728.63     728.63       0               728.63
20130714        1401.629   2251.39      94.418          1307.211
20130715        583.956    5089.19      583.956         0
20130805        6317.277   8958         2629.566        3687.711
```

I want the output like below.(The columns might change dynamically, needs to calculate Sum by row wise)

```
ID              Q1         Q2           Q3            Q4             SUM(Q1:Q4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
20130712        NULL       728.63       NULL            NULL         728.63   
20130712        8881.55    9673.68      2629.566        6251.984     27436.78
20130713        1813       1813         84.49           1728.51      5439
20130714        3632.65    3632.65      1209.412        2423.238     ...
20130714        70.758     2637.43      70.758          0
20130714        1601.578   3569.73      204.745         1396.833
20130714        728.63     728.63       0               728.63
20130714        1401.629   2251.39      94.418          1307.211
20130715        583.956    5089.19      583.956         0
20130805        6317.277   8958         2629.566        3687.711
```

Comment: The output is just the original table without the `Total` column. Did you get them backwards?

Answer (score 23):

You haven't shown your query attempt, but it's probably something like this:

```
SELECT
  ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,
  Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 AS "Total"
FROM MyTable
```

If any of the `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, or `Q4` values are null, `Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4` will be null. To treat the nulls as zero and get a proper sum, do this instead:

```
SELECT
  ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,
  COALESCE(Q1,0) + COALESCE(Q2,0) + COALESCE(Q3,0) + COALESCE(Q4,0) AS "Total"
FROM MyTable
```

The [`COALESCE` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) will return the first non-null value in the list.

Comment: Yet another option is to use NVL function, e.g: NVL(Q1, 0) which returns Q1 if Q1 is not NULL and 0 if Q1 is NULL

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - don't think SQL Server has `NVL`. And `COALESCE` is standard/portable.

Comment: Needs some assistant: The columns in a result set may be increase or decrease then if we hard core column names, the query may not give correct results. So can please help me for dynamic query.

Comment: @user1613094 - there are two ways to do a dynamic query: (1) use your front-end language to assemble and run the query or (2) write a SQL Server procedure that uses `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`. I recommend posting a new question specifically about dynamic SQL, and when you post the new question please (a) include some working SQL and (b) be careful to get the table and output right - I'm pretty sure you had them switched for this question, and it's hard to get help if a question is confusing.

Comment: works flawlessly @EdGibbs

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it there's a shorter way, but the most elegant I can do is:

```
select
    ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4,
    (
         select sum(S.Q)
         from (values (Q1), (Q2), (Q3), (Q4)) as S(Q)
         where S.Q is not null
    ) as [Total]
from Table1 as T
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8fbc/2)

If you want dynamic SQL, try something like

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max), @stmt1 nvarchar(max)

select
    @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + name,
    @stmt1 = isnull(@stmt1 + ', ', '') + '(' + name + ')'
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('Table1') and name not in ('ID')

select @stmt =
          'select ID, ' + @stmt + 
          ', (select sum(S.Q) from (values ' + @stmt1 +
          ') as S(Q) where S.Q is not null) as [Total] ' +
          'from Table1 as T'

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8fbc/12)

Comment: Needs some assistant: The columns in a result set may be increase or decrease then if we hard core column names, the query may not give correct results. So can please help me for dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Roman Pekar, If you're using a temp table and want to do this, you need to use tempdb like this:

```
select
@stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + '[' + name + ']',
@stmt1 = isnull(@stmt1 + ', ', '') + '(' + '[' + name + ']'+  ')'
from tempdb.sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..##TempTable') and name not in ('ID')
--ID would be one of the column names you DONT want to sum.
--also notice the double pound sign. you need to declare your temp table with double pounds or it wont work
--also notice how I put brackets around name, that's because my columns weren't working because they had slashes in their names.
--the rest of the code is the same
select @stmt =
          'select Date_Packed, ' + @stmt + '' + 
          ', (select sum(S.Q) from (values ' + @stmt1 +
          ') as S(Q) where S.Q is not null) as [Total] ' +
          'from tempdb..##TempTableas T'
          print @stmt

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
--don't forget to drop it
          drop table ##TempTable
```