# Calculate sum of rows in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a table like [image]

converted row values into columns by using pivot

```
Select 
    StudentName, EC1, EC2, EC3, EC4, EC5 
from 
    tblStudent
Pivot 
    (Sum(Marks) for subject in ([EC1], [EC2], [EC3], [EC4], [EC5])
    ) as PivotTable
```

[image]

Now I want to add a new column after EC5 with name Toatl values will be sum of all 5 subjects

I tried using temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #StudentTemp  
(  
    StudentName varchar(20),  
    EC1 int,EC2 int,EC3 int,EC4 int,EC5 int 
)  
GO  

INSERT INTO #StudentTemp  
    SELECT StudentName, EC1, EC2, EC3, EC4, EC5 
    FROM tblStudent
    PIVOT
        (SUM(Marks) for subject in ([EC1], [EC2], [EC3], [EC4], [EC5])
        ) as PivotTable 

SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(EC1 + EC2 + EC3 + EC4 + EC5) AS Total 
FROM
    #StudentTemp 
GROUP BY
    StudentName
```

After this I tried to join

```
SELECT *
FROM #StudentTemp sp 
INNER JOIN tblStudent s ON sp.StudentName = s.StudentName
GROUP BY s.StudentName 

SELECT StudentName, SUM(EC1 + EC2 + EC3 + EC4 + EC5) AS Total
FROM #StudentTemp
GROUP BY StudentName

SELECT SUM(EC1 + EC2),* 
FROM #StudentTemp 
GROUP BY StudentName
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246143/calculate-row-wise-sum-sql-server

Comment: show your table definition for tblstudent

Comment: create table tblstudent (StudentId int, StudentName varchar(20),Subject varchar(10),Marks int)