# Can anyone tell me how to find sum in database row wise

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm writing this code

```
SELECT (Mathematics+Tech_comm.+Prog_C) As Total FROM sem1
```

and its throwing error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+Prog_C) As Total FROM sem1 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: `Tech_comm.` what is this period for?

Comment: Hi Deepak please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246143/calculate-row-wise-sum-sql-server I think this will help you.

Comment: If this is a column name [Tech_comm.] with a dot, you need to add backticks ` `Tech_comm.` `

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE sem1`

Answer (score -1):

SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) as Total FROM table